# How can I correctly convert this?

Tags: django

I tried a couple of times converting this date format

```
Wed, 02 April 2015 15:50:53 SAST
```

to this format

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]
```

but with no luck so far. 
Is there any better way to this, that I might have missed?

Here's what I attempted:

```
date = Wed, 02 April 2015 15:50:53 SAST
splitter = date.split(" ")
joiner = " ".join(splitter[1:len(splitter)-1])
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(joiner,"%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
date = datetime.datetime.strftime(date,"%A, %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
```

When I'm saving it to the db, I'm receiving this error:

```
[Wed, 02 April 2015 15:50:53 SAST for that value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

Comment: Where is your code which indicates that you was trying?

Comment: @vishes_shell here's the code and error in the question

Comment: Please post your model. Is the field a `datetimefield`?

Comment: @ilse2005 date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

Comment: edited my answer. You are trying to save a `str` as `date`

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) (str --> time) and [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) (date --> str).

### EDIT:

You are trying to save a string to a `DateTimeField`. Just remove the string conversion (`strftime`).

Comment: This is the error I'm receiving [Wed, 02 April 2015 15:50:53 SASTfor that value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Comment: after joiner, when I print joiner, I've this 02 April 2015 15:50:53 SAST, I want it to be in this format:  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]

Comment: Why? If you want to save it as `DateTimeField` just add a `datetime` instance --> remove the `strptime` line.

Comment: it's giving me this error: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Please edit your question and post all relevant code (including your models)